# Sorting and Limiting data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Please have a look at the below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(`word`) AS count FROM `key_uniqueword` group by `word`
```

Now, I need to sort the result according to the `count` in descending order. After that, I need only the first 200 records in the sorted list. How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: did you try adding a `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(word) AS count FROM key_uniqueword group by word ORDER BY count LIMIT 200` right? This will first limit the records even before ordering, am I correct? I need to "Sort first Limit second"

Comment: Did you even try it? (Hint: that should just work)

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Yeah I tried it, but I have doubt about the thing. This table got 7 billion data, so I can't even check..

Comment: as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107882/mysql-using-count-and-limit-functions-together), limit is applied after count.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic:hI, After count, before sort?

Comment: sort first,then limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`word`) AS count 
FROM `key_uniqueword` 
GROUP BY `word` 
ORDER BY count LIMIT 200
```